# mod_rewrite: Redirect to page named in GET variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm changing the directory/URL structure on a site to make it more legible (and, of course, pretty), and I've run into a snag. Let's say I have the following URI request:

`http://example.com/page.php?foo=bar&baz=qux`

If someone has bookmarked the old URI, I want to redirect that request in `.htaccess` to a page determined by the `foo` variable, like so:

`http://example.com/bar`

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

## Edit

Here's a more concrete example. I used to have a page called `cc.php`. It was called with two parameters: `curriculum` and `title`. So, a query might look like `cc.php?curriculum=lesson1&title=First%20Steps`. This is obviously very ugly, so I want to redirect it to `/lesson1`

I removed the old `cc.php` and created a new `index.php` that figures out which curriculum to display based on the request URI. If a visitor goes to `/lesson1`, it automatically knows what to do via the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]`
```

There's a chance someone has bookmarked the old `cc.php` scheme, however, so I want to be able to rewrite to the new scheme if someone does that. I've tried the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^curriculum=(.*)&title=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^cc.php$ %1
```

While this will correctly redirect `cc.php?curriculum=lesson1&title=some_title` to `/lesson1`, it will *not* work in conjunction with the previous rule.

How can I get both sets of rules working? The other solution I've thought of is to have a `cc.php` that calls `header()` based on `$_GET['curriculum']`, but that seems ugly.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You just need to redirect the old URL format to the new one. Can you post the code you have tried for the new URL structure?

Comment: @starkeen I updated the original post with more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Redirect flag **[R]** in you rule to externally redirect the request from old URL format to the new one.

```
 RewriteCond ℅{QUERY _STRING} ^curriculum=([^&]+)&title=(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^cc.php$ %1? [L,R]

 RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```